# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

How do you fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
even = None
def is_even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even = True
        return even
    elif num % 2 != 0:
        even = False
        return even

def lastmes():
    if even == True:
        text = "The last value of even is True"
    elif even == False:
        text = "The last value of even is False"
    return text

print(lastmes())
print(is_even(51))
```

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(lastmes())
  File "main.py", line 15, in lastmes
    return text
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `even` is None. In `lastmes` both if-conditions are unsatisfied. Therefore `text` does not get set to anything. So trying to return it causes an exception.

Comment: The value for even is None when you are running the code. That's why the program is not going into any of the definitions of text. So effectively you are returning a variable which does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do 3 things.

First, make `even` variable inside the `is_even` function global. You are just creating another local variable and setting it's value which wont change the `even` you created outside the function.

```py
def is_even(num):
    global even #Here
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even = True
        return even
    elif num % 2 != 0: #You should change this to just an else but this works too
        even = False
        return even
```

Second, change the `elif` in your `lastmes` function to `else`. If you plan on using `elif` and want to consider a possibility for `even` to be `None`, then you should add another `else` to deal with the `None` possibility.

```py
def lastmes():
    if even == True:
        text = "The last value of even is True"
    else:
        text = "The last value of even is False"
    return text
```

Third, call `is_even` before `lastmes` so that the values are calculated, before checking them and displaying the messages.

```py
print(is_even(50))
print(lastmes())
```

Answer (score 1):

If `even` is neither `True` nor `False`, then `text` is never defined. `even` is set to `None` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: But then then in the other function i get an undefined error

Comment: Good! You've fixed one problem. Now you have another. If you can't fix it, ask another question about it. (One problem, one question.)

Comment: thank you but the answer above answered my question