# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ip_addressa' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, telnet

Im using telnetlib.Telnet function to connect to telnet devices but I can't figure out how to fix error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ip_addressa' referenced before assignment
None , I saw [UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668454/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-text-referenced-before-assignment) and [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)but that did not helped me, so here is my code

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import traceback
 
def h4ck_th3_w0rld(HOST):
    user = 'admin'
    password = 'password'
    tn = None
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 23, 11)
 
        tn.read_until("Username: ", 7)
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password: ", 7)
            tn.write(password + "\n")

    for a in range(200, 256):
        for b in range(7, 7):
            ip_addressa = '192.168.%d.%d' % (b, a)
          
            print(ip_addressa)
 

    tn.write("cd /var/tmp\n")
    tn.write("./busybox telnet" + ip_addressa + "\n")
        tn.write("exit\n")
 
        print(tn.read_all())
    except Exception as e:
        #print traceback.print_exc()
        print 'Error occurred'
    finally:
        if tn:
            tn.close()
 
 
for i in range(205, 206):
    for j in range(7, 8):
        ip_address = '192.168.%d.%d' % (j, i)
        h4ck_th3_w0rld(ip_address)
        print(ip_address)
```

So Im getting an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ip_addressa' referenced before assignment None`

Answer (score 2):

Please post the traceback so we can see the failing line. And consider boiling this down to a minimal example that we can run to test. As stands I just have to guess. But...

```
    for b in range(7, 7):
        ip_addressa = '192.168.%d.%d' % (b, a)
        print(ip_addressa)
```

`range(7,7)` doesn't iterate anything so the loop doesn't run, `ip_addressa` isn't assigned and nothing is printed. What that range should be depends on how many addresses you want to iterate.

You have other problems in the posted code, like the `for` is not indented properly inside the "try/except" which is a syntax error. And `tn.write("cd /var/tmp\n")` should be **inside** the `for`. Maybe there is some tabs to spaces thing going on, so I can't really say.