# Getting UnboundLocalError while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I got this error while scraping:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tag' referenced before assignment

and it seems caused by

> ---> 17     return tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__date").text, tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__title").text,
> tag.find_next(class_="b-plainlist__announce").text.strip()

The code I am using is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd

daterange = pd.date_range('02-25-2015', '09-16-2020', freq='D')

def main(req, date):
    r = req.get(f"website/{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.select(".b-plainlist "):
        print(tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__date").text)
        print(tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__title").text)
        print(tag.find_next(class_="b-plainlist__announce").text.strip())
    
    return tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__date").text, tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__title").text, tag.find_next(class_="b-plainlist__announce").text.strip()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, date) for date in daterange]
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.append(f.result()) # the problem should be from here
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            allin, columns=["Date", "Title", "Content"])
```

I tried to apply some changes like in this post: [UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668454/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-text-referenced-before-assignment), but I think I have not fully understood how fixing it.

Update: this is the response of the website and the content of `print (soup.select("b-plainlist"))`

> <Response [503]> b'\n\n\n
> \n    HTTP 503\n    \n
>
> \n        html {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,
> Arial, sans-serif;}\n        body
> {background-color:#fff;padding:15px;}\n        div.title
> {font-size:32px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2em;}\n       
> div.sub-title {font-size:25px;}\n        div.descr
> {margin-top:40px;}\n        div.footer {margin-top:80px;color:#777;}\n
> div.guru {font-size:12px;color:#ccc;}\n    \n\n\n
> \n        503 Error\n 
> Service Unavailable\n\n        \n
>
> Try accessing the website
> it.sputniknews.com in a few minutes.
>
> \n
>
> If the error
> repeats several times, contact the site administration.
>
> \n       
> \n\n        \n            \n                IP: 107.181.177.10
> \n              
> Request: GET L3BvbGl0aWNhLzIwMTUwMzA4
> \n                Guru
> meditation: MGV1SjNTaWhuUHNiblJYVU96QVpxMDB6N1hDNjU5NTU=
> \n       
> \n        \n\n    \n\n\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the tag=None right outside your for loop like follows

```
def main(req, date):
r = req.get(f"website/{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tag=None
for tag in soup.select(".b-plainlist "):
```

The error occurs as the control never enters the loop and in-turn, variable 'tag' is never initialized. Hence when you try to return tag.select_one(".b-plainlist__date"), the compiler throws an UnboundLocalError

Comment: I think this error is caused by that None. Something does not work when I run the for loop and append the results in allin

Comment: Are you able to print the response from the website? Please do a print(r, r.content) right above soup=BeautifulSoup(...). I want to make sure you are actually getting a response.

Comment: While you are at it, can you please also print soup.select("b-plainlist") ?. I quickly glanced through the HTML you provided and am not able to see any tags with the above mentioned class.

Comment: I am not sure if the classes I have used are right, so it might be that they are wrong, though I can see the outputs. This is the response: <Response [503]> b'<!DOCTYPE html>. For the other print, please see the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Response code 503 means service unavailable. This hence is not a BeautifulSoup error. There is something wrong with the request that you are making using the 'requests' module. Ideally, you should get a 200 code when you make a default GET request. I would suggest calling the URL using POSTMAN and debugging what is wrong with your request